# Triggering stage with rules

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, rules, singularity-container

I developed a gitlab pipeline with several stages and builds, now I would like to be able to specify which builds are going to be executed. Ideally I would like to detect the changes under docker_dir/*, but right now I cannot get code to trigger the build.

```
.ci_rules:
  rules:
    - if: '$IS_JOB_ON == "TRUE"'
      when: always

.job_template: &start_docker
  variables:
    BUCKET: "ci-jupyterhub-singularity"
  tags:
    - autoscale-large
  rules:
    - !reference [ .ci_rules, rules ]
  script:
    - echo "start job"

build:
  stage: build_docker_image
  <<: *start_docker
  before_script:
    - export IS_JOB_ON="TRUE"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rules:` are evaluated at the time the pipeline graph is generated. Because `rules:` are used to make the pipeline in the first place, you cannot use the output of a variable exported in a job to affect `rules:` evaluation in the same pipeline.

However, [detecting changes is a builtin rule feature](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#ruleschanges). For example, to trigger a job when any file changes in the `docker_dir/` directory (including subdirectories) you can do the following:

```yaml
rules:
  - changes:
    - docker_dir/**/*
```

Comment: Thanks, would your suggestion work if docker_dir is exported as $DOCKER_DIR from the before_script?

Comment: does not seem to work guess for the same reason.

Comment: @fabio.geraci right, as explained, `rules:` are evaluated before the pipeline even starts, so you can't `export` a variable and use it in a rule in the same pipeline. You can set a variable in `variables:` or your project CI/CD settings though.